# XML encoding unprintable characters?

Tags: xml, encoding

If I wanted to send a XML message in something like a HTTP Post and I want to have a binary attribute, how would I encode this properly? The content-type: text/xml char-set: utf-8

I've read around the web and many say that we only need to escape things like <, >, ", ', and . However, I've also read that it is incorrect to include unprintable characters with a few exceptions.

Say I wanted to encode the binary value 0x01020304. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use base64 encoding.

(Padding, stack overflow doesn't like short answers)

Comment: But how do I know if the server will be accepting base64 encoding? Wouldn't that depend on whoever is taking this HTTP Post?

Comment: If the server has already defined how the attribute should be encoded, then you obviously have to encode it that way, so why are you asking the question?